# How to program an Arduino Uno Pro with a makefile?

Tags: arduino-uno, compile, makefile

I'm using [Arduino Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile) to compile sketches for Uno and Mega boards. I'm now trying to compile a sketch for an [Arduino Uno Pro](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/arduino-uno-pro), which is an Uno with a replaced chip to give it features more like a Mega.

When writing a makefile to compile for this board, which `BOARD_TAG` should I use? I don't see this board listed in the official Arduino or Arduino Makefile docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you edit your `boards.txt` file to incorporate the Arduino Uno Pro section from near the end of that [Arduino Uno Pro webpage](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/arduino-uno-pro) at hobbytronics.co.uk that you referenced, the board tag list produced by `make show_boards` will include the following line:

```
uno_pro       Arduino Uno*Pro
```

indicating the tag should be `uno_pro`.

Comment: I also had to copy over a `pins_arduino.h` file, but yeah, that was it. I thought it required something more the makefile.

Comment: @Cerin, glad you got it to work ... I've been impressed by the documentation quality and the ease of use of this particular Arduino Makefile system.  BTW, if copying the pins_arduino.h file fixed the other problem you posted, you probably could either delete that question or answer it.